# Removing sub-folders in Python

Tags: python, shutil

I have an main folder(map) under this main have sub folder (zoom1,zoom2,zoom3...)
how can i remove sub folder using shutil. 
note * : I know the main folder path sub folders are dynamically created

Answer (score 3):

If you're using linux you could do the following.
Use python's [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) library

Lets you have a directory structure with the following structure.

- /map

  - /map/zoom1/
  - /map/zoom2/
  - /map/zoom3/

Using [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) and [shutil](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html)

```
import glob
import shutil

sub_folders_pathname = '/map/zoom*/'
sub_folders_list = glob.glob(sub_folder_pathname)
for sub_folder in sub_folders_list:
    shutil.rmtree(sub_folder)
```

*sub_folders_pathname* is a shell-style wildcard, [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) supports shell-style wildcards.

*sub_folders_list* are a list of folders and then we  use [shutil.rmtree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) to remove it.